# AngularJS app showing Redirect Loop error after deploying to Apache server

Tags: apache, angularjs, gruntjs, web-deployment, yeoman

I'm rather new to AngularJS and I have a problem with deploying my project to an Apache server.

1. I generated an app with Yeoman
2. Did some coding
3. While coding I used `grunt serve` and everything was working fine
4. When I wanted to test it on my server, I used `grunt build`
5. Uploaded content of my dist folder to my server and now after I open my page I get "This webpage has a redirect loop" error on Chrome and "The page isn't redirecting properly" on Firefox (I guess other browser would show more or less the same message)

I tried posting a normal HTML page, that works fine. Also, I don't believe there is a problem with my code (at least with the part I've coded) so I generated a clean project with Yeoman and tried to deploy that - same Redirect loop error.

Internet searching didn't really help (probably because I didn't search for the right question).

Any suggestions would help. Thanks in advance

SOLVED: The problem was I was deploying my app to my-domain.com/something, after i deployed it to subdomain.my-domain.com it worked ok.

Comment: I actually didn't set $locationProvider @dfsq

Comment: @dfsq, I set up html5Mode(true).hasPrefix('!'); and added <base href="/">, still nothing